# Setting a Date range on CSV Exports in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have a button on the show page of CaseMain that exports specific child records (Billedtimes and Lineitems) for that case (one_to_many relationships). I would like to add a start and end date selector next to the export button, and then export only items within that date range. I have been unable to find a tutorial that matches this use case.

The CaseMain show page:

```
<%= link_to "Export Billed Items", case_main_path(format: "csv"),class: 'btn btn-outline-success btn-small btn-block'%>
```

The CaseMain controller:

```
def show
    @case_mains = CaseMain.where(:id => @case_main.id).limit(10)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.csv { send_data @case_mains.to_csv, filename: "case-#{Date.today}.csv"}
    end
  end
```

The CaseMain model:

```
  def self.to_csv
    desired_columns = ["Client Code",
                       "Case Name" ,
                       "Date",
                       "Description",
                       "Hours",
                       "Charge",
    ]
    CSV.generate(headers: true) do |csv|
      # Header columns
      csv << desired_columns

      all.includes(:client, :billedtimes, :lineitems).find_each do |case_main|
        case_main.billedtimes.find_each do |time|
          csv <<
              [
                  time.case_main.client.client_code,
                  time.case_main.case_name,
                  time.billedtime_date,
                  time.billedtime_description,
                  time.billedtime_hours,
                  time.billedtime_total
              ]
      end

        case_main.lineitems.find_each do |line|
        csv <<
            [
                line.case_main.client.client_code,
                line.case_main.case_name,
                line.lineitem_date.to_date,
                line.lineitem_description,
                ' ',
                line.lineitem_total
            ]
      end
    end
    end
    end
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

So, basically you need to query `billeditems` and `lineitems` tables.

Your query should look smth like this, just replace `your_first_date` and `your_second_date` with the range you want to search.

`CaseMain.joins(:billeditems, :lineitems).where(:id => @case_main.id).where(billeditems: { date: your_first_date..your_second_date }).where(lineitems: { date: your_first_date..your_second_date })`